# GPIO32 pin works in analog mode, always reads 0 in digital mode

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

I'm having some difficulty getting PCNT pulse counting working with a prototype ESP32 device board.

I have a water level sensor (model D2LS-A) that signals state by the frequency of a square wave signal it sends to GPIO32 (20Hz, 50Hz, 100Hz, 200Hz, 400Hz).

Sadly, the PCNT counter stays at 0.

To troubleshoot, I tried putting GPIO32 in ADC mode (attenuation 0, 10-bit mode) to read the raw signal (sampling it many times a second), and I'm getting values that I would expect (0-1023). But trying the same thing using digital GPIO mode, it always returns 0, never 1 in all the samples.

Since the PCNT ESP IDF component depends on reading the pin digitally, the counter never increments past 0.

So the real problem I'm having is: why aren't the ADC readings (between 0-1023) translating to digital readings of 0-1 as one would expect?

Comment: Hi Geoff, we can't help you without your code. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Tarmo - it looks like the root cause of this problem is something to do with the prototype board. When switching to an off-the-shelf dev board, the code works just fine on various pins.